# Find biggest of three numbers

Tags: shell, unix, sh

Write a shell script to find out biggest of three numbers. Assume that inputs are given as command line argument, and if this three numbers are not given show error message as "*command line arguments are missing*".

My script is here, but I'm getting errors for all are equal and not equal options... plz hellpppp me...

```
if [ $# -eq 3 ]; then
   if [ $1 -eq $2 -eq $3 ]; then
       echo "All numbers are equal"
   elif [  $1 -eq $2 -ne $3 ||  $2 -eq $3 -ne $2 ||  $1 -eq $3 -ne $2 ]; then
       echo "I can't figure out which number is greater"
   elif [ $1 -gt $3 && $1 -gt $3 ]; then
       echo "$1 is the biggest number"
   elif [ $2 -gt $3 ]; then
       echo "$2 is the biggest number"
   else
       echo "$3 is the biggest number"
   fi
else
   echo "command line args are missing"
fi
```

Comment: Have you heard about indentation?

Comment: For debugging, run it with -x. Also add `echo $#` and `echo "$@"` to your last *else* branch. If you get this result, the number of parameters is obviously different from 3.

Answer (score 0):

Observations:

1. If the user enters four or more numbers, the error message "*command
   line args are missing*" would be wrong.
2. The `-eq` syntax doesn't allow `1 -eq 2 -eq 3`.  Running it returns
   a "`bash: [: too many arguments`" error.  The same goes for `-ne`.
3. The `||`s should be replaced with `-o` or `] || [`.
4. This test is no good:  `$1 -gt $3 && $1 -gt $3`.

   - The first `$3` should be a `$2`.
   - `&&` should be replaced with `] && [` or `-a`.
5. The test and output for `"I can't figure out which number is greater"` is needless.  If *A=B* and *B>C*, just print *A*.

Answer (score 0):

Your two main problems are trying to chain `-eq` (you need to use two separate `[` commands) and trying to use `||` and `&&` inside `[` (again, use separate commands). Your second case doesn't make sense; integers are well-ordered, so if the three aren't equal, then there is going to be a largest value. You can replace `-eq` with `-lt` in your `$#` check to simply ignore any additional arguments.

As always, you should quote parameter expansions to avoid unexpected argument values from breaking your code.

```
if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
   if [ "$1" -eq "$2" ] && [ "$2" -eq "$3" ]; then
       echo "All numbers are equal"
   elif [ "$1" -gt "$2" ] && [ "$1" -gt "$3" ]; then
       echo "$1 is the biggest number"
   elif [ "$2" -gt "$3" ]; then
       echo "$2 is the biggest number"
   else
       echo "$3 is the biggest number"
   fi
else
   echo "command line args are missing"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 3 ]
then
         if [ $1 -gt $2 ] && [ $1 -gt $3 ]
         then
         echo "$1 is Biggest number"

         elif [ $2 -gt $1 ] &&  [ $2 -gt $3 ]
         then
         echo "$2 is Biggest number"

         elif [ $3 -gt $1 ] && [ $3 -gt $1 ]
         then
         echo "$3 is Biggest number"
         fi
else
echo "command line arguments are missing"
fi
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the correct answer:**

```
if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then 
    echo "command line arguments are missing"
elif [ $1 -eq $2 ]&&[ $2 -eq $3 ]
then
    echo "All the three are equal"
elif [ $1 -eq $2 ]||[ $1 -eq $3 ]
then
    echo "I cannot figure out which number is biggest"
elif [ $1 -gt $2 ]
then
    if [ $1 -gt $3 ]
    then
        echo "$1 is biggest number"
    else
        echo "$3 is biggest number"
    fi
elif [ $2 -gt $3 ]
then
    echo "$2 is biggest number"
else
    echo

 "$3 is biggest number"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and neat looking code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#find largest among three
read a
read b
read c
if [ $a -eq $b ] && [ $b -eq $c ]
then
echo "All the three numbers are equal"
elif [ $a -eq $b ] || [ $b -eq $c ] || [ $a -eq $c ]
then
echo "I cannot figure out which number is largest"
else

if [ $a -gt $b ] && [ $a -gt $c ]
then
echo "$a is largest number"
elif [ $b -gt $c ] && [ $b -gt $a ]
then
echo "$b is largest number"
else
echo "$c is largest number"
fi
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

for finding whether three numbers are equal or not and greatest of three numbers

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ”enter 3 numbers”
read a
read b
read c
if [$a –eq $b –a $a –eq $c]
then
echo “3 number are equal”
elif [$a –gt $b –a $a –gt $c]
then
echo ”$a is the greatest number”
elif [$b –gt $c]
then
echo “$b is the greatest number”
else
echo “$c is the greatest number”
fi
```

Comment: There are numerous problems with this, some of which appear due to copy-and-pasting from a word processor.